# Python: Read URL's from text file and save result error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using the the following code to read the URL's in a text files and save the results in an another text file

```
import requests

with open('text.txt', 'r') as f: #text file containing the URLS
    for url in f:
        f = requests.get(url)
        print (url)
        print(f.text) 
        file=open("output.txt", "a") #output file
```

For some reason I am getting a `{"error":"Permission denied"}` message for each URL. I can paste the URL in the browser and get the correct response. I also tried with the following code and it worked OK on a singular URL.

```
import requests

link = "http://vanhatpainetutkartat.maanmittauslaitos.fi/getFiles.php?path=W50%2F4%2F4524"
f = requests.get(link)
print(f.text, file=open("output11.txt", "a"))
```

The txt file contains the following urls

```
http://vanhatpainetutkartat.maanmittauslaitos.fi/getFiles.php?path=22_Topografikartta_20k%2F3%2F3742%2F374207
http://vanhatpainetutkartat.maanmittauslaitos.fi/getFiles.php?path=W50%2F4%2F4524
http://vanhatpainetutkartat.maanmittauslaitos.fi/getFiles.php?path=W50%2F4%2F4432
http://vanhatpainetutkartat.maanmittauslaitos.fi/getFiles.php?path=21_Peruskartta_20k%2F3%2F3341%2F334112
```

I assume I am missing something very simple...Any clues?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line has a trailing newline. Simply strip it:

```
for url in f:
    url = url.rstrip('\n')
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use content from the response-
you can use this code in loop

```
import requests

download_url="http://vanhatpainetutkartat.maanmittauslaitos.fi/getFiles.php?path=W50%2F4%2F4524"

response = requests.get(download_url, stream = True)
with open("document.txt", 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response.content)
    file.close()
print("Completed")
```